# Write int to binary file in C

Tags: c, getline, atoi

I have to open a file, which contains every number in new line. ( represented as string )

To read data I need to use getline().

To change data from string to int, I need to use atoi().

To write changed data to file, I need to use write().


What I managed to do is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fopen("stevila.txt", "r");

    FILE *fd = fopen("test.bin", "w+");

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int a=10;
    char str[8192];


    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
        strcpy(str, line);
        int val = atoi(str);
        write(fd, val, a);
    }

    free(line);
    fclose(stream);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Thanks to the answers, I managed to create a program that works :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("text.txt","r");

    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR; /* Allow user to Read/Write file */
    int fd = open("out.bin",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,mode);

    if (f==NULL) {
        perror("Error while opening 'text.txt' ");
        return -1;
    }
    if(fd < 0){
        perror("Error while opening 'out.bin' ");
        return -1;
    }

    size_t max_size=64;
    char* line;
    line=malloc(max_size);

    int d;
    while ((d=getline(&line, &max_size, f))!=-1)
    {
        int tmp=atoi(line); /* Change string to int and save it to tmp */
        if(write(fd,&tmp,sizeof(tmp)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Error while writing data ");
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    close(fd);
    free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Now we can run this command in terminal, to see if the output file is as expected:

```
od -i out.bin
```

Comment: `printf("%s", fd);` --- uhhh... this is definitely not what you intend it to be.

Comment: It is commented out, so it is not working..

Comment: I edited my code now sry i had it in comments because i was trying dfferent things

Comment: `write(fd, val, a);` also is not what you want it to be. `write()` does not take a `FILE *` parameter.

Comment: use `fwrite` instead.

Comment: Voted for close because question is `why this code doesn't work?`

Comment: You're mixing different I/O APIs - either use `fwrite` with `fopen`, or use `write` with `open`.

Comment: @Alex there's nothing wrong with "why doesn't this code work" questions... but more information in the question would be helpful (such as how the OP knows it's not working/what should be happening/etc.).

Comment: @mah I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `FILE*` as an argument to `write`. You have the following options:

1. Use `fwrite`. The signature of `fwrite` is:

   ```
   size_t fwrite( const void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count,
                  FILE *stream );
   ```
2. Get the file descriptor from a `FILE*` using the function `fileno` and use `write`. The signature of `fileno` is:

   ```
   int fileno(const FILE *stream);
   ```

   The signature of `write` is

   ```
   ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
   ```

   Your use of `write` is not correct. You are passing a `val`, which is not the address of a variable. You are using `a` as the third argument. That needs to be changed to:

   ```
   write(fd, &val, sizeof(val));
   ```
3. Use `open` instead of `fopen`.

My recommendation will be to use `fwrite`. It is a standard C library function whereas `write` is not.

Also, make sure to open the file in binary mode. Instead of using `"w+"`, use `"wb"`.

```
FILE *fd = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
```

Add a line to close the file before exiting. If you use `fopen` to open the file, use `fclose` to close it. If you use `open` to open the file, use `close` to close it.

Comment: You should probably include that the file handle should be closed as well.

Comment: Third option: use `open` instead of `fopen`. :)

Comment: @lurker, that is another option

Answer (score 2):

`write` takes a file descriptor as opposed to a file pointer.
On a linux O/S for example.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/write

Why not just use the fwrite function to do what you need

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/

You can use the file pointer returned from `fopen` with this function and print as required.

Comment: `fprintf()` doesn/t put out binary data, which the question suggests is the requirement here. `fwrite()` does however, as suggested in @EugeneSh's comment.

Comment: updated.  that's the function I was thinking of. thanks